# How do i find out what attributes in a python class are callable?

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes, callable

```
sample_list = []

for attribute in dir(sample_list):
    if callable(attribute):
        print(attribute)
```

I'm writing this code to find out what attributes of `sample_list` are callable. I know the `list` class has callable attributes like `append` and `pop` but none of them seem to show up. why's this?

Comment: `attribute` is a string. A string isn't callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attribute` is a string. A string isn't callable. You're missing [`getattr(sample_list, attribute)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
sample_list = []

for attribute in dir(sample_list):
    value = getattr(sample_list, attribute)
    if callable(value):
        print(attribute)
```